# How can i make operation from dbCommand result in yii 1

Tags: php, yii

I am beginer in Yii app, i wan to ask

How can i get the total value of 'rata_nilai' to total nilai. rata nilai is the result from dbCommand. I have try to count rata nilai in dbCommand but it doesnt work. Please help

```
$total = Yii::app()->db->createCommand() 
    ->select('Nama_Team,blueteam_id, laporan_id, (sum(nilai_penjelasan)+sum(nilai_gambar))/count(laporan_id) as total') 
    ->from('LaporanHardening l') ->Join('Penilaian_Hardening p', 'l.id=p.laporan_id')
    ->group('laporan_id') 
    ->order('Nama_Team desc') 
    ->queryAll();

$this->widget('ext.groupgridview.GroupGridView', 
    array( 
        'id' => 'Laporan-grid',
         'dataProvider' => $dp3,
         'mergeColumns' => array('Nama_Team', 'total_nilai'),
         'columns' => array(
             array( 
                'header' => 'Nomor',
                 'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage*$this->grid->dataPr‌​ovider->pagination->pageSize + $row+1',
                 'name' => 'total_nilai', 
                 'value' => '(count($data["rata_nilai"]))', //this is get error ))
        ,));
```

Comment: please share your code so it can be improved

Comment: this is my code from the controller and view.
a.Controller

Comment: this is my code from the controller 
$total = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('Nama_Team,blueteam_id, laporan_id, (sum(nilai_penjelasan)+sum(nilai_gambar))/count(laporan_id) as total')
                ->from('LaporanHardening l')
                ->Join('Penilaian_Hardening p', 'l.id=p.laporan_id')
                ->group('laporan_id')
                ->order('Nama_Team desc')
                ->queryAll();

Comment: this is from my view 
$this->widget('ext.groupgridview.GroupGridView', array(
    'id' => 'Laporan-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dp3,
    'mergeColumns' => array('Nama_Team', 'total_nilai'),
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'header' => 'Nomor',  'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage*$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + $row+1',
            'name' => 'total_nilai',
            'value' => '(count($data["rata_nilai"]))', //this is get error
        )),));
?>